# Django-jfu Object [object Object] has no method 'fileupload'

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-file-upload

I am using Django-jfu(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jfu) to enable file uploading in my site. But I receive this error message in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fileupload'
```

The function using fileupload is:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        formData: [
            { name: "csrfmiddlewaretoken", value: "S96vL7eMvCvRInQ5ezuQqWT3bhOOUzDz"}
        ],



autoUpload: true,
maxNumberOfFiles: 5,
sequentialUploads: true,
acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
maxFileSize: 2000000,
minFileSize: 50000,


    });
```

And the included js are:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="/static/demo/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/demo/load-image.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/demo/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/demo/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.fileupload-video.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
```

I think the function named "fileupload" is not correctly called or the function is missing. Can anyone help me on this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact error as reported by your browser? It seems very unlikely that a method named `'file upload'` (with embedded space) is being called.

Comment: Hi, Lanzz. Sorry for the confusion. It should be "fileupload"

Comment: You seem to be loading the `fileupload`-related JS files last; if the `$('#fileupload').fileupload(...)` line is not within an `onready` handler for your document, it might be invoked before the `fileupload` plugin is loaded.

Comment: Hi, I fixed this bug. The problem is that I loaded jQuery.js after this block of js. "fileupload" function is added to the customised jQuery in this plugin but I override the customised one, so the function cannot be found. I hope this can help someone else if they also have this problem.